# Regex to get string out after the first OU=

Tags: .net, regex

So I have this string `CN=Jcombat,OU=Users,OU=US,OU=Support,DC=alphas,DC=akman,DC=net`.

I have this regex to give me everything including the first `OU`, so the final string should look like this: `OU=Users,OU=US,OU=Support,DC=alphas,DC=akman,DC=net`.

Shouldn't this pattern `(?=-\"OU=")` give me what I need?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using LDAP query with Nintex workflow which uses .net RegEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OU=.*$
```

Should do it for you.

or

```
(?=OU=).*$
```

`(?=OU=)` will give you a position where you have `OU=` ahead of it , but you need to consume it as well. `?=` is just an assertion.It does not consume string.

Comment: Perfect OU=.*$ does the job. Thanks VKS

Answer (score 1):

Positive Lookahead [`(?= ... )`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds) is a zero-width assertion which does not "consume" any characters on the string, but only asserts whether a match is possible or not. You could match everything from "OU=" to the end of the string.

```
String s = "CN=Jcombat,OU=Users,OU=US,OU=Support,DC=alphas,DC=akman,DC=net";
Match m  = Regex.Match(s, @"OU=.*");
if (m.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value); //=> "OU=Users,OU=US,OU=Support,DC=alphas,DC=akman,DC=net"
```

Comment: Just saw your reply as well. Thanks for your feedback and code.